# Which settings in Betaflight allows me to do flips and rolls?

Tags: betaflight, quadcopters, aerobatics

I see a lot of people flipping and rolling their quads, but on my last attempt, it fell out of the sky.

What are the settings in Betaflight that allow them to do this without stopping the motors?

Answer (score 7):

It’s called Airmode.

It keeps the motors in a constant idle state, even at zero throttle. This gives you pitch, roll and yaw authority even when you are upside down.

You can enable it in the configuration tab in Betaflight.

You will notice that your props may try to spool up even when your quad is just sitting armed on the floor, but this is called I term ramp-up and is completely normal.

I tend to keep Airmode on all the time so have it set up in the configuration tab, but you can also map it to a switch in the modes tab so you only have it on when you want it.

Comment: A little bit of pedantry: The setting that keeps the motors at a constant idle is called _idle up_. Airmode actually keeps them at the very minimum that's required to stabilize the drone in its current state and spools them up only as required. In that respect it's superior, as it eliminates the constant thrust at zero throttle when the quad doesn't need it.

Comment: Also, a worthy note: having airmode on a switch has the benefit of the quad not jumping up like crazy if you bump it into something, for example when landing. It may be useful to have if you want to bring the quad down gently instead of disarming it while still in the air half a meter from the ground, or are doing advanced freestyle maneuvers like wall taps and don't want it to power itself off the wall as soon as it touches it.

Comment: Final worthy note for beginners - you'll need to be in "acro" mode to do flips. The other two flight modes ("angle" & "self-level") won't give you the complete freedom you need for aerobatics.

Comment: imean *technically* there's "horizon" mode on most firmwares, but it's not a good habit to learn.